# How to launch PHP on Atom?

Tags: php, browser, server, atom-editor

While changing file from .html to .php extension it shows me message that there is no PHP interpreter found at php. And it is not about script support it is should launch on the browser. Clicking the "the set PHP" button it shows me the ide-php package. And I see no way how to set the Path.

[Atom settings.PHP settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7yZI.png)

Answer (score 1):

you cant run php without a server, you need to install XAMPP (in case of windows you could use WAMP or in case of mac you could use MAMP).
you can download XAMPP from the link below:
https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, but MAMP I prefer more, anyway